# Execute function in ELF file to extract flag

Tags: linux, binary, elf

I have an ELF file (f-x64) that I am trying to extract a flag from. I don't have much experience with this. Along with a lot of other things, I have tried using `gdb` and then `info functions` to view the functions, where I see one called `getFlag` - this looks promising. I then try to run that function, hoping it will print the flag, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it:`run getFlag`, where I get the output:

```
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/path/f-x64 getFlag
Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004006bd in main ()
```

When I run the main function I get the same output.

This is the output from `info functions`:

```
Non-debugging symbols:
0x00000000004004b8  _init
0x00000000004004f0  puts@plt
0x0000000000400500  __stack_chk_fail@plt
0x0000000000400510  printf@plt
0x0000000000400520  __libc_start_main@plt
0x0000000000400530  __isoc99_scanf@plt
0x0000000000400540  __gmon_start__@plt
0x0000000000400550  _start
0x0000000000400580  deregister_tm_clones
0x00000000004005c0  register_tm_clones
0x0000000000400600  __do_global_dtors_aux
0x0000000000400620  frame_dummy
0x0000000000400646  getFlag
0x0000000000400657  rot13
0x00000000004006b9  main
0x0000000000400740  __libc_csu_init
0x00000000004007b0  __libc_csu_fini
0x00000000004007b4  _fini
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: did you try the [`strings`](https://sites.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/cmds/aixcmds5/strings.htm) command?

Comment: **UPDATE** I added a breakpoint: `break main` and then used call `((void(*)()) getFlag)()` and got the output:`It's not going to be that easy`, so now I am kind of lost as to where to search for this flag!

Comment: @AvenDesta Yes and it outputs a list of functions/outputs/etc., none of which are the requested flag format